# Need to make DatasetV1Adapter a Dataset for NN training

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to load csv to dataset for training NN

```
# load a csv
CSV_PATH = './dataset.csv'
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(CSV_PATH, batch_size)

#Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
#Create a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    #Training epoch
    for epoch in range(number_epochs):
        #Get one batch of images
        batch_x, batch_y = dataset.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        #Run the optimizer feeding the network with the batch
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
        #Display the epoch (just every 100)
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%d' % (epoch))
```

On execution I get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/afickbohm/Desktop/pyfiles/IDM/metis.py", line 63, in 
    batch_x, batch_y = dataset.train.next_batch(batch_size)
AttributeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'train'

So, dataset isn't type Dataset. How do I do this?